# Helm chart using Terraform helm provider - error executing consecutive charts

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, istio

I have to install helm charts using Terraform helm provider. I tried introducing a delay after executing the first as there is a prerequisite to finish installation of the first chart and dependency before the second helm chart is installed. With the below provision script:

```
resource "helm_release" "istio-init" {
  name       = "istio-init"
  repository = "${data.helm_repository.istio.metadata.0.name}"
  chart      = "istio-init"
  version    = "${var.istio_version}"
  namespace  = "${var.istio_namespace}"
}

resource "null_resource" "delay" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sleep 200"
  }

  depends_on = ["helm_release.istio-init"]
}

resource "helm_release" "istio" {
  name       = "istio"
  repository = "${data.helm_repository.istio.metadata.0.name}"
  chart      = "istio"
  version    = "${var.istio_version}"
  namespace  = "${var.istio_namespace}"
}
```

I see the "null_resource" delay module runs when the terraform provisioning for the first time. When tried deleting the resources and reran the Terraform script I see the null_resource module never gets executed again and the provisioning errors out. Are Terraform provisioners designed to run only once?

Answer (score 2):

Helm has an optional wait flag that actually will block the release until all resources are up. If you specify the `wait` variable on your `helm_release` resource, Terraform (and Helm under the hood) will wait for all resources to be up.

For example:

```
resource "helm_release" "istio-init" {
  name       = "istio-init"
  repository = "${data.helm_repository.istio.metadata.0.name}"
  chart      = "istio-init"
  version    = "${var.istio_version}"
  namespace  = "${var.istio_namespace}"
  wait       = true
  timeout    = 200
}
```

Comment: Do you have a snippet example of how to do it ?

Comment: Added a snippet.

Comment: On a side note, to answer your question related to the null resource. Terraform provisioners are meant to be reran. But the question is how did you delete the resources?

Comment: I think I deleted the resource manually and tried a Terraform apply which was the primary reason for the null resource not running when I tried applying the plan. I did a Terraform destroy and apply again which was running okay .....

Comment: Yeah that would have been my guess as well.